# Restricting access to some pages in Django

Tags: django, django-views

In my Django project, I want only the **premium users** to be able to access the sales page. So if a user's `user_type` is **Trial**, he/she can't be able to access sales page. For these non-premium users, I want to display another html `(upgrade.html)` to them

Below is my view

```
class SalesView(TemplateView, SingleTableView):
    model = Product
    table_class = ProductTable
    template_name = 'src/dashboard/sales.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        ...
        ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # my contexts goes here
```

And this is my url

```
path('sales', SalesView.as_view(), name='sales'),
```

This is the normal view. Now I want to stop **Trial** users from accessing this page.
Please how can I achieve this?
My model has a field `user_type` which tells whether a user is a **Trial** or **Premium** user

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django roles to define roles for the user and limit access to the page using the role. The default role will be **Trial** in your case. This blog might be helpful

https://medium.com/djangotube/django-roles-groups-and-permissions-introduction-a54d1070544